# Run gradle Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am working with the Gradle build system in the Eclipse IDE. Whenever I create Gradle project in Java I always need to go to command prompt and then to specific project directory and build it first through command gradle build followed with the my corporate proxy settings. I am not able to build it directly from the IDE. can anyone suggest Where I can add my proxy setting to make it build and run my Gradle project from the Eclipse IDE directly rather than going to command prompt always.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can define the proxy settings in `gradle.properties` in your root project directory if it is the same for anyone using that repository, or in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` to set it for any Gradle project on your machine but not affecting other users of the repository.

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) for further information about the proper syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply I tried doing that but still I have to go to command prompt to build the project but this time I don't have to give my proxy settings but going to command prompt and then building project is still the same.

Comment: If it works from the commandline now, I think it should work from Eclipse too, as Eclipse is doing the same as the commandline, which is tellilng the Gradle daemon to build the thing.

Comment: Yes! It is working now the problem was I was proving the wrong path in Gradle_USER_HOME(Windows-Prefrences-Gradle). I changed the path to point to the .gradle directory and its working now. Many thanks!!